# why does this C input function crash?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int input(char *s, int n){

    char c;
    int i = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && i < n){
          s[i++] = c; // assigns s[i] then does i++
    }

    s[i]= '\0';

    return i;
}

int main() {

    char array[10];

    input(array, 10);

    printf("%s", array);

}
```

I have written this code but it does not work.

When i input something it crashes and my shell aborts. Why is this?

Comment: Running your program in a debugger should immediately show you where it crashes. You can then inspect variables that are involved in the previous instruction.

Comment: As you said it crashed whenever you input 'something', seems not true. If you are getting crash because odf entering more than 9 characters than it could be because of your smaller array `array[10]` as suggested by @kiran . If any other reason for crash then please elaborate more.

Comment: Note that `getchar()` returns an `int`. Google why this is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s[i]= '\0';
```

This will access the array out of bound when you enter more than 9 characters.

To prevent this read max `n-1` chars.

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && i < n-1){
```